# Problem with nxt_lejos installation on ROS Hydro

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install nxt_lejos on ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Hydro following the official ROS documentation and by also referring to some answers found on forums. I've followed these steps:

1. successfully installed rosjava following this
   [tutorial](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html)
   with several corrections from this
   [forum](http://answers.ros.org/question/63403/problem-with-rosjava-installation/?answer=63453#post-id-63453)
   (obviously changing all the references to ROS version to hydro-devel)
2. successfully installed lejos as prescribed the official tutorial from lejos.org website
3. trying to install nxt_lejos following this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/nxt_lejos/Installation) (section 1.2)

once launching shell command 'gradle installApp' I get the following error:

20:12:25.603 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

20:12:25.606 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]

20:12:25.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:

20:12:25.609 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
':nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy:compile'.

20:12:25.610 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not find ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

20:12:25.612 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   Searched in the following locations:

20:12:25.617 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       file:/root/.m2/repository/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

20:12:25.619 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       file:/root/.m2/repository/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/rosjava-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

20:12:25.621 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       file:/root/.m2/repository/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/rosjava-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

20:12:25.624 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       [dead_repo](http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml)

20:12:25.625 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       [dead_repo](http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/rosjava-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom)

20:12:25.643 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       [dead_repo](http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/rosjava-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)

20:12:25.653 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   Required by:

20:12:25.654 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       ros.nxt_lejos:nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT

based on what I have read so far on this  [forum](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/issues/178)

it looks like the ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT artifact has been removed and the robotbrains repository closed;

so I have tried to modify the build.gradle file in each project included in nxt_lejos accordingly to use a newer version of the artifact (org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.1.+) and a [new repository](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master) but I'm still getting a similar error (the same error as above with just a different missing artifact)

How can I install nxt_lejos avoiding these errors?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/184833/problem-with-nxt_lejos-installation-on-ros-hydro/) by [dros](https://answers.ros.org/users/19556/dros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the repository has indeed been closed, then there will be no later versions here... I do not know this for a fact, so I cannot post an answer. Perhaps get in touch with the maintainers.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0